# Google Chrome error "FileSystemDirectoryEntry" does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have downloaded the latest chrome and firefox, my code does the following:

1. Receives a **FileSystemEntry** and
2. Does one thing for **FileSystemDirectoryEntry**
3. Another for **FileSystemFileEntry**

All this classes are part of the [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem), however, I get this error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: FileSystemDirectoryEntry is not defined
```

And if I log the item, right before the error, it indicates this:

```
DirectoryEntry {
  isFile: false, 
  isDirectory: true, 
  name: 'Videos', 
  fullPath: '/Videos', 
  filesystem: DOMFileSystem
}
```

---

The part of the code doing the logging is:

```js
/**
 * Function is limited to traverse the system and limited to jpeg and png files
 * @param item FileSystemEntry
 * @param files - this input array will be mutated
 * Note: The callbacks are promisified to allow for async/await.
 */
export async function readFileSystem(
  item: FileSystemEntry,
  files: File[],
  types = /.(jpe?g|png)$/i
) {
  console.log(item);
  if (item instanceof FileSystemDirectoryEntry) {
    const directoryReader = item.createReader();
    ...
```

So I don't get if this is a bug or how should I use it. Any explanations please?

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this was to remove the instance of check, and use this function:

```js
export async function readFileSystem(
// same arguments than OP
) {
  if (item.isDirectory) { // <---- only change here and interface below
    const directoryReader = (item as FileSystemDirectoryEntry).createReader();
   // ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because Google Chrome does not conform to the standard yet. You can (re)define names like this

```
const FileSystemDirectoryEntry =
  window.FileSystemDirectoryEntry || window.DirectoryEntry;
const FileSystemEntry = window.FileSystemEntry || window.Entry;
```

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Firefox_support#chrome_deviations_from_the_specification) for details.